# Boost/Python: How can I use/convert extracted objects?

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

Suppose:

```
using namespace boost::python;
void myClass::test(numeric::array& arrayParam) {
    const tuple &shape = extract<tuple>(arrayParam.attr("shape"));
}
```

I would like to transform it to an int and print for example. I tried `int x = shape[0];` but it gives me a "cannot convert ‘boost::python::api::const_object_item’ to ‘int’ in initialization" message.

Answer (score 10):

`shape[0]` gives you a Python object. To convert it to an `int` or another C++ type, you need to extract the value:

```
int x = extract<int>(shape[0]);
```